# 'jQuery not defined' for Google Maps/Advanced Custom Fields/JointsWP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

Working in WordPress with Advanced Custom Fields and using JointsWP (Foundation 5) theme. Building a map that shows multiple pins from a custom post type and using the Google Map field from Advanced Custom Fields. I've done this exact work before on Bootstrap3 and it worked easily. Code is from the tutorial on [ACF forum here](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/multiple-post-points-on-google-maps/).

My map will not show. In Console I get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.  JointsWP theme most likely, as the exact code I'm using worked perfectly in BS3. I am calling Google Maps API with wp_enqueue_script in my functions.php.

Any help is really appreciated!

The js -

```js
<?php get_header(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {

 /* render_map */

 function render_map( $el ) {

  // var
  var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

  // vars
  var args = {
   zoom  : 16,
   center  : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
   mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
  
  // create map          
  var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

  // add a markers reference
  map.markers = []; 
   
  // add markers
  $markers.each(function(){

   add_marker( $(this), map );

  });

  // center map
  center_map( map ); 
  }

  // create info window outside of each - then tell that singular infowindow to swap content based on click
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content  : '' 
 });

 /* add_marker */

 function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

 // var
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

 // create marker
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position : latlng,
  map   : map
 });

 // add to array
 map.markers.push( marker );

 // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
 if( $marker.html() )
 {
  // show info window when marker is clicked & close other markers
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   //swap content of that singular infowindow
     infowindow.setContent($marker.html());
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  
  // close info window when map is clicked
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          if (infowindow) {
              infowindow.close(); }
    });  
 }

 }

 /* center_map */

  function center_map( map ) {

   // vars
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   // loop through all markers and create bounds
   $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

  });

   // only 1 marker?
   if( map.markers.length == 1 )
   {
    // set center of map
       map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
       map.setZoom( 16 );
   }
   else
   {
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
   }

  }

  /* document ready*/

  (document).ready(function(){
   $('.acf-map').each(function(){
    render_map( $(this) );
   });
  });

 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

PHP template -

```
<div class="acf-map">

                    <?php while ( $mapposts->have_posts() ) : $mapposts->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                    $location = get_field('map_address_condo_project');
                    $gtemp = explode (',',  implode($location));
                    $coord = explode (',', implode($gtemp));
                    ?>

                    <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location[lat]; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location[lng]; ?>">
                        <p class="address"><?php  echo $gtemp[0]; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>       
                    </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div><!-- .acf-map -->

                <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious to me, jQuery isn't included yet. you'll need to make sure your code is included AFTER jQuery is included, which may change based on how the template is built.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, man. That was it. Moved my script to the footer after `<?php get_footer (); ?>`. In console, the load order was showing jQuery loading first, but I guess that was not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the script is being enqueued after jQuery. JointsWP loads jQuery in the footer, but this can easily be moved into the header. In the assets/functions/enqueue-scripts.php:

**Load jQuery in Footer:**

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js', array(), '2.1.3', true );

**Load jQuery in Header:**

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js', array(), '2.1.3', false );

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyE  Exactly what I was looking for. However, if I wanted to create a .js file specifically for my map function in the assets/js/ folder, would I still need to change the loading order? Or could I just add my script to the assets/js/site/init-foundation.js  file?

Comment: It depends. Are you using something like Gulp/Grunt to compile/minify your JS? If so, you can throw the .js file into the assets/js/site folder and have it compile into the main JS file. Or you can simply enqueue the script directly.

I tend to compile and minify all of my scripts into one file.

Comment: I'm using CodeKit to compile. I like the idea of minifying into the main JS file. Thank you for your time @JeremyE and great job on JointsWP!